# I can't find anything about this problem in xcode

Tags: xcode

Xcode just continues to say "iPhone is not available because pairing is in progress", but when I connect my phone and select "trust", xcode just keeps saying that without reacting. I cannot view the iPhone in the "Devices and Simulators" window (see image).

[[Devices and Simulators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVx2q.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y5qM.png)

I would much appreciate if anyone can help me come closer to fixing this issue.

I have tried everything I could find on the web about device connecting issues for a while, but found no one with this specific issue. I have tried all the other stuff from people with issues connecting their device, like updating xcode, restarting my device and so on, but none of that has fixed this issue.

Comment: what phone do you have? updated iOS?

Comment: I have an iPhone 15 and it is updated to the latest IOS update

Comment: how about trying different cables?

Comment: Yeah tried different cables too. Maybe I should try on a different phone. Or re-installing xcode

Comment: Alright so it works to build it on a different phone. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with mine, but for now I'll be using a different phone. Thanks for the help mjr